# Custom HTML::macro() is giving me a BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I've added a custom HTML::macro() to my laravel application like so:

- app/macros.php: http://paste.laravel.com/TjZ
- app/start/global.php: http://paste.laravel.com/Tk0

Running the application in the browser is working excellent – no problem at all!
But once I run my controller tests I keep getting following error message:

> BadMethodCallException : Method activeNavLink does not exist.

Any ideas, what I could do to turn it green?

Best Regards and thanks in advance, Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App::before should be used for procedural code, not registering macros or extensions. Moving the HTML::macro out of the App::before closure should work.

Comment: I've had a problem with my tests, also removed the App::before from my macro like you said, now all my tests turned green. Thank you!